# Magento multiselect attribute behavior in layered navigation

Tags: magento, attributes, navigation, multi-select, layered

I'm using the layered navigation of Magento to let the users select filters to determine their choice.
Because I have a large set of choices, I chose to use multiselect attributes so that the amount of attributes would be smaller.

The normal Magento behavior is as follows (i.e. shoes): 
- User wants to find red and yellow shoes, using filter "Color"
- User selects "Red" and "Yellow" as filter options and that's it.

In my case, the selected options are depending on each other.
For instance when the user can filter on application.
- User wants to find a product that can be used in the kitchen and also in the living room.

When this user selects "Kitchen" and "Living room" as filter options and the possible products do not fit in a "bathroom", the filter option "Bathroom" has to disappear.

I've tried to do this using seperate select-attributes with only one option, but the amount of attributes keeps on growing and I'm losing overview while doing this.

How can I change the behavior of a multiselect attribute in Magento for the layered navigation, based on above example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the behavior of layered navigation you need to rewrite the layered navigation in Block/Layer/.. and Model/Layer

You can use Mana Filters Modules that will allow you to have multiple filters from same type, then you can implement your own filter class for select( example price filter it has its own class in layered navigation ) etc .. !

http://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

There is also paid module amasty layered navigation